# Write text next to series of equalities

Tags: math-mode, equations, align, amsmath

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Self-Inverse_Elements_Commute_iff_Product_is_Self-Inverse

How do I align descriptions of each equation like this? Using align puts the text to far to the right side of the page. Is there a preferred method for TeX users to label inequalities like this in general?

[image: Align text like this]

Comment: What you try so far?

Comment: @Zarko Basically variants of align and array that I found on other posts. Nothing looked quite standard (i.e. something that I would read in a textbook) so I thought there must be a way that regular users of TeX prefer to do this. I'm more trying to understand if there is a consensus on how to typset something like this in general.

Comment: It looks like this display was formatted with `align`, using two `&` before the text notations.  The first line would end thus: `&& \textnormal{$\circ$ is associative} \\ `.  I'm sure there's another question on this already, but haven't looked for it (but try the "related" list to the right of the question).

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for your reply. I will keep looking through the other questions. Do you know how to standardize the distance so that all of the text explanations are aligned as in the picture, and allow moving the entire block towards/away from the margin?

Comment: You can use flalign and add \hspace{...} before the last &, but i can't think of anyway to choose the distance other than trial and error.  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224115/clean-way-to-write-a-two-column-proof

Comment: This question is about the same sort of construction: [Horizontal spacing after equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44056)

Comment: You should show us what you done. It is not fun to retype your image knowing, that you already have its code. Apparently you not willing to help us to help you!

Comment: @Zarko I don't have its code! And I never asked to retype this image. I was asking if there is a consensus in the mathematical TeX community of how best to typeset a string of equalities similar to this, as as I have seen almost identical labeling of equalities in several papers and textbooks. The image was just an example to show the form I am talking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by John Kormylo one can do this.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        (x\circ y) \circ (x\circ y) & = x\circ (y\circ x)\circ y & &\textnormal{$\circ$ is \color{blue}{associative}}\\
        & = x \circ (x\circ y) \circ y & &\textnormal{$x$ and $y$ \textcolor{blue}{commute}}\\
        & = (x\circ x) \circ (y \circ y) & &\textnormal{$\circ$ is \textcolor{blue}{associative}}\\
        & = e_G \circ e_G & & \textnormal{$x$ and $y$ are \textcolor{blue}{self-inverse}}\\
        & = e_G & & \textnormal{Definition of \textcolor{blue}{Identity Element}}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that you are using `\color` the wrong way. It is `\textcolor` that takes two arguments. You get the intended result by happy coincidence because the group ends.

Comment: Okay, yeah true. Thanks for this. I edited the solution.